# Uncaught TypeError: Object is not iterable when using useReducer with useContext for global store React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-context, use-reducer

I am trying to use hooks to replace the redux store with action and reducers
I have created a global store using createContext and a global reducer using useReducer and trying to use the global state object with useContext in the below file which is throwing error. Also, I have tried console logging the return value of `useContext(Store)` which is giving undefined.

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react'
import {newAction} from './actions'
import Store from '../../utils/store'
const Home = ()=>{
    console.log(Store)
    const [appStore, dispatch] = useContext(Store)
    useEffect(()=>{
        
        dispatch(newAction())
        console.log(appStore)
    },[]) 
    return(<div>Hello there</div>)
}

export default Home
```

Getting error `index.jsx:7 Uncaught TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) at Home (index.jsx:7) at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)` at line `const [appStore, dispatch] = useContext(Store)`

My **App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Home from './pages/home';
import './styles/index.scss'
import {StoreProvider} from './utils/store'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <StoreProvider>
      <Home/>
    </StoreProvider>
    
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My **Store/index.js**

```
import {createContext} from 'react'

const Store = createContext({});

export const StoreProvider = Store.Provider;

export default Store;
```

**contextProvider.js**

```
import React,{useReducer} from 'react';
import {ContextProvider} from './index'
import reducer from './combineReducer'

const initialState = { home:{} }

const StoreProvider = (props) =>{
    return <ContextProvider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {props.children}
    </ContextProvider>
}
export default StoreProvider
```

**combineReducer.js**

```
import homeReducer from '../../pages/home/reducer'
export default mainReducer = (initialState, action)=>{
    return({
        home: homeReducer(initialState.home, action)
    })
}
```

**home/reducer.js**

```
import {NEW_ACTION} from './actions'
export default reducer = (state,action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case NEW_ACTION: return {...state, val:true}
        default: return state
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you do const [appStore, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState); then give both appStore and dispatch to the provider and use them.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier where should I use this?

Comment: context provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were few mistakes in the code in the following files:

1. in file **Store/index.js** rename variable `StoreProvider` to
   `ContextProvider` as i am using `ContextProvider` which is not defined there.
2. in file **App.js** change the import line `import {StoreProvider} from './utils/store'` to `import StoreProvider from './utils/store/contextProvider'` as provider is written in contextProvider file.

Files after fixes:

**Store/index.js**

```
import {createContext} from 'react'
const Store = createContext({});
export const ContextProvider = Store.Provider;
export default Store;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Home from './pages/home';
import './styles/index.scss'
import StoreProvider from './utils/store/contextProvider'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <StoreProvider>
      <Home/>
    </StoreProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```